# javascript fail - regexp bug

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Hei all

I have this code

```
function prototype( str , id )
{
    var ret = str;

    ret = ret.replace( /ø/g, 'oe' );
    ret = ret.replace( /Ø/g, 'OE' );
    ret = ret.replace( /å/g, 'aa' );
    ret = ret.replace( /Å/g, 'AA' );
    ret = ret.replace( /æ/g, 'ae' );
    ret = ret.replace( /Æ/g, 'AE' );

    document.getElementById( id ).value = ret.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/\_-]/i,'_').replace(/_+/g,'_');
}
```

My problem is now, if i use word like this (`demo demo demo`) its okay make this word to (`demo_demo demo`)

i use this function to escape urls. the next i need its send it to lower case, after I'm done, i hope for help :)

tanks a lot all.

Comment: ok, but where and when your code fails?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. What's the problem with your script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the greedy-modifier

```
/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/\_-]/i
```

....

```
/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/\_-]/ig
```

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is that only the first space gets replaced with `_`, then you need to put the `g` option to the regex replace.

```
ret.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/\_-]/gi,'_')
```

to turn the string to lower case use the

[`toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) method of strings.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your 1st requirement is to replace space, +, - characters with underscore,

```
document.getElementById( id ).value = ret.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/\_-]/ig,'_').replace(/_+/ig,'_');
```

Other requirement is to make it lowercase string

```
document.getElementById( id ).value = document.getElementById( id ).value.toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

The main potential issue I see, is on first replacement (on Ø and other scandinavian characters).

you should change with unicode char representation, e.g. this statement

```
ret = ret.replace( /Ø/g, 'OE' );
```

should be

```
ret = ret.replace( /\u0153/g, 'OE' );
```

for other diacritic signs just find a unicode chart like http://www.chucke.com/entities.html